# Can SQL Server use a fulltext index for a LIKE query?

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, sql-like, full-text-indexing

I wish to avoid a fullscan for a query using the `LIKE` keyword:

```
SELECT * 
FROM MYTABLE 
WHERE MYCOLUMN LIKE '%WORD%'` AND PRICE < 3;
```

With SQL Server, we can define a fulltext index and use it with the `CONTAINS` clause (and other ones). The problem: I'm not allowed to change my query, so I want the server use the fulltext index with the `LIKE`keyword.

Is it possible?

Comment: You can't. You either need to use `CONTAINS` (with a Full Text Index) or drop the leading Wild Card; which won't provide the same result. Using `LIKE` with a leading Wild Card makes a query non-SARGable. I suspect that this is an XY Problem; why can't you make use on `CONTAINS`? You say you can't change your query; why?

Comment: Because the query is automatically generated by a software and I cannot change the code of this software.

Answer (score -1):

You could increase the performance by using the folowing trick:

```
WHERE MYCOLUMN LIKE 'WORD%' 
AND MYCOLUMN LIKE '%WORD'
AND PRICE < 3;
```